# Background Images - what is wrong with my code?

Tags: image, css, background-image

I simply cannot get this code to work. I want to put a different background image on each page. I think I should do this by creating different class selectors, and then putting those in the body tags for each page, rather than using an inline style element.

Here's my css class selector:

```
    .contact-grad
{
        background-image:url('images/Backgrounds/contact-grad.png');
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        z-index:-1;
}
```

And here I put it in the html for contact:

```
<body id="contact-grad">
```

As you can see, it's not working.

Let me know if it will be helpful for me to post the entire html and css. I cannot get any background image to work. I put my code into the w3 validator, and got a "parse" error. Hm...

Thank you!

Comment: Oops, here is the site.
http://violetoeuvre.com/contact.html

Answer (score 1):

The body has an id 'contact-grad' but your selector in the css is on a class (that's what the dot do). Try using a hash '#' instead. as in

```
#contact-grad
{
    background-image:url('images/Backgrounds/contact-grad.png');
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

**Addendum**:
[This](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/) resource is a good starter for CSS-selectors.

Comment: ah! yes i knew that. i switched it but it's still not working!
#contact-grad
{
        background-image:url('images/Backgrounds/contact-grad.png');
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        z-index:-1;
}

Comment: hm, that's weird. When I apply the style to the body-element in the webdeveloper tools I see the background image. What 'parse' error did you get when validating the page?

Comment: It was for my homepage, violetoeuvre.com.
Parse Error /* Class Selector : Apply to as many elements as you like */ <style> .box_nav { display:block; background: rgba(255,255,255,.75); width:1000px; height: 320px; padding:30px; border:0px ; margin-top:10px; margin-left:100px; }

Answer (score 0):

`.contact-grad` is for a class, use `#contact-grad` for your `id="contact-grad"`.

You shouldn't have your body as absolute position, better use a div inside the body ;).